# How to use lettrine with diacritics and makebox?

Tags: lettrine, octavo

In `\documentclass[titlepage]{octavo}` using `\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}` I want to use `lettrine` with a letter containing a diacritic sign from the Slovak language:

```
\lettrine{\v{S}}{}
```

Which should end as: `Š`

This works as expected. The problem occurs when I try to use it with `makebox` command:

```
\makebox[.85em][c]{\lettrine{\v{S}}{}}
```

This will not get compiled, it ends with `Missing \endgroup inserted.` error. If I remove the diacritics, it works (e.g.: `\makebox[.85em][c]{\lettrine{S}{}}` works nicely).

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{octavo}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgchorus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}
    
% This works
\makebox[.85em][c]{\lettrine{S}{}}alom.
    
% This does not (comment this out to compile)
\makebox[.85em][c]{\lettrine{\v{S}}{}}alom.

\end{document}
```

If I omit `\makebox` command, the layout does not look good:

[image: Without makebox command]

As compared to one with makebox:

[image]

Comment: Please add your MWE.

Comment: @ferahfeza sorry, I have updated the question

Comment: Is there a reason you use the `\makebox` and not just `\lettrine` directly?

Comment: @DavidPurton Layout stuff, check the update on the answer

Comment: You can configure `lettrine` to adjust the spacing however you want. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `lettrine`. It has many options to adjust spacing. Check the manual for details.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{octavo}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tgchorus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{}

\begin{document}
\makebox[.85em][c]{\lettrine{S}{}}alom.

\bigskip

\lettrine[findent=0.2em,nindent=0pt]{\v{S}}{alom.}

\bigskip

\lettrine[findent=0.2em,nindent=0pt]{\v{S}}{alom.} This is some long text
designed to go on to the next line in order to see what happens. Usually it
takes a long long time in order to produce text that is long enough.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out, and if everything's OK, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

This is build with `lualatex` (because it is the only thing I use), which need utf-8 encoding, `fontspec` package, and OpenType or TrueType fonts.

```
\documentclass{article} % Build with lualatex. Use utf-8 encoding.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\makebox[.85em][c]{\lettrine{\smash{Š}}{}}alom.
\end{document}
```

The trick is the `\smash` command. Apparently the caron does not fit in the box, unless you do that.

[image: result of above code]

Probably the horizontal alignment could be improved. How I know about `\smash` is because my programming skill is limited to using a sledgehammer.